Dynamically formatting input text to a TextBlock from a string using various delimiters
I want to parse an input string and bold/italicize/underline the portions of the text encapsulated within certain characters.
 Ex: I have had a _really_ *bad day*.

In this case, "really" would be italicized, and "bad day" would be in bold.
It's tricky because sometimes the desired formatted items might be nested in other formatted portions.
 Ex: I have had the *worst day _ever_*. 

In this case, "worst day ever" would be bold, and "ever" would be bold AND italicized.
Does anyone have a method they use that they'd care to share? Thanks!

You arent talking about how you want to format the strings: HTML, MD, Rich Text, etc.
Perhaps check out some libraries for the output format you want to use before you re-invent the wheel.

You should try the MarkDownTextBlock from the CommunityToolkit and avoid inventing the wheel.
<controls:MarkdownTextBlock Text="**This is *Markdown*!**" />

